# Search a string and extracting the size or quantity values from a string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'm trying to automatically extract all the size and quantities out of the titles of all my products in a database. So I need to extract the size or quantity preceding some text.

for example in the following string and I need to extract the the number of cases (1000).

> "Micromesh II Biopsy Processing/Embedding Cassettes, 4 Compartment,
>   White - 1000/Case"

I need a way of searching through the string for the string "/Case" and then extracting the prior 4 characters. I was looking at using sub string and removing the last 5 characters but some of the descriptions in my database are different and I can't do this.

Is this possible in `VB.NET`?

Comment: There are 1000 cases, not 100 :-) :-) I hope your code will extract more exactly :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Will a / always indicate there are numbers preceding it? Why shouldn't the 4 of "4 Compartment" be found?

Comment: An essential skill for just about any programmer: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Do you have a preference for doing this all on the database side or all in VB.NET?  Also what is your database engine?

Comment: I have no preference, if I can do it in the database using SQL that would be easier. I'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started.  Dont' really know what your delimitors are.  Just that the number come before the /.

```
Dim s As String = "Micromesh II Biopsy Processing/Embedding Cassettes, 4 Compartment, White - 1000/Case"
Dim idxSlash As Integer = s.LastIndexOf("/")
Dim idxStart As Integer = idxSlash - 1
While Char.IsDigit(s(idxStart))
  idxStart -= 1
End While
Dim result As String = s.Substring(idxStart, idxSlash - idxStart)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx).

This will give you the position you need to use with `Substring`.

Not tested:

```
myString = myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf("/Case") - 4, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions. It will work faster

Answer (score 1):

First of all find out a common pattern for your products name. and then write a **Regular Expression** that can find all your targets. then you can use `Regex` class and `Match` method in vb.net or c# to extract those. it think Regular Expression is the best choice for doing that.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: @Oded - I know it's hard to write perfect regular expression manually because of this I often use expression tools like _Expresso_

Answer (score 0):

@Oded's is good, but breaks if the number isn't 4 digits. So:

```
    ' Works as long as number is preceded by space and followed by /
    s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf("/")).Substring(s.LastIndexOf(" "))
```